# Honorific and humble forms of suru verbs

Tags: verbs, conjugations, honorifics

This question is about suru-verbs,
verbs made from a noun and the verb suru (for ex: 鼓 + する).
I am familiar with the potential form of suru being 出来る,
then suru-verbs potential become Xしえる or Xしうる or Xせる.
How would you conjugate suru-verbs into the honorific and humble forms?
I know なさる is the honorific form and 致す is the humble form of suru.

I took a couple guesses...

鼓する > 鼓なさる

鼓する > お鼓しになる

Comment: According to this https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/AMB_Japanese_Verbs.pdf

honorific would be お + stem + なさる
can anyone verify?

Comment: The potential form of suru-verbs is Xできる, not Xしえる etc, which have a different meaning from Xできる. 鼓する is only found in kanbun and 鼓なさる or お鼓しになる are practically not used.

Comment: I have seen about 101 sites that will disagree with Xできる being the potential form of a suru-verb

Comment: Aside from terminology, what's important is that ◯しえる is different from ◯できる and that the conjugation like 書く → 書ける share the same meaning as ◯できる, not ◯しえる.

Comment: so what is the difference between Xしえる and Xできる?

Comment: し得る means that there's possibility for something to happen while できる and potential forms mean that the agent has ability or right to do something. For example, when you translate "the situation can go wrong", you can say 状況は悪くなり得る but not 状況は悪くなれる.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plain: 利用する
honorific: ご利用になる
humble: 利用させて頂く、利用致します

https://townwork.net/magazine/knowhow/manners/baito_manners/13309/

Answer (score 1):

I don't really hear single-kanji-suru-verbs conjugate into honorific or humble forms except 信じられる or rarely 信じなさる (honorific). If you dare to want humble versions, I'm afraid you have to use 信じ申し上げる.

As for two-kanji versions, I hear both 信頼される and 信頼なさる evenly. The humble version 信頼いたす is common this time.

Comment: It is for the sake of completeness, I am creating an app for conjugation of japanese verbs

Comment: That's a very difficult job, you won't be able to avoid some unpractical combinations.